# Python nested for one-liner

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following `for` loop:

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for f in foo:
    for b in f:
        d[b] += 1
```

I ripped my actual example of bloat which is unrelated to my question. Now I want to somehow shorten it. In e.g. list comprehensions we are allowed to use nested `for` loops, and if they're done properly they can be perfectly readable. So we reduce nesting and the amount of lines. My question here is, can we do nested `for` loops without doing the comprehension, so we would end with something like this, in Python?:

`d[b] += 1 for b in for f in foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
for b in itertools.chain.from_iterable(foo): d[b] += 1
```

Notice that when trying to do this `d[b] += 1 for b in for f in foo` (which is of course invalid sintax) your intention is to **mutate** something, and that **should not** be done inside a comprehension.

Comment: +1. Additionally, `collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(foo))` should simplify it even further

Comment: What if I need to pass `f` to some other function, in my case: `for b in windowed(f, 2)`?

Comment: @dabljues, I would stick to the nested for loop in that case. I think it would be the most readable thing to do.

Comment: Sorry for my absence. Yeah, I guess you're right. Marking your answer as accepted, thank you!